# I need help in the MATLAB code I have written for Graphene Bilayer bands in the first BZ

Tags: matlab, physics

[image: This is the band structure I am getting for the Bilayer graphene along kx]

I am trying to write a code for the bilayer graphene and restrict the calculations in the 1st Bz. But somehow, even if I sort the bands and the kx wavevectors, the bands are not coming as expected. I had used a square lattice before where kx and ky were both arrays from (-Kx to Kx) and (-Ky, Ky) (Kx, Ky are the position of the Dirac points), and the results were good. I want to do the calculation only in the 1st BZ since I intend to do some physical properties calculations like magnetic moment, etc. I have posted the code I have written using MATLAB and the Bands I am getting using it. I believe the bands do not make sense and cannot find a way out. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

```
clear, clc;
format long

% Define lattice 

parameters for graphene
a = 1.42; % Carbon-carbon bond length in Ångstroms


% Define hopping parameters
t0 = 2.9;
t1 = 0.33;
% Reciprocal lattice vectors
G1 = (2*pi/3*a) * [1, sqrt(3)];
G2 = (2*pi/3*a) * [1, -sqrt(3)];

% Number of k-points per dimension
N = 60; % Adjust N for desired k-point density
%%
% Initialize arrays to store k-points and bands
kx_points = zeros(N*N, 1);
ky_points = zeros(N*N, 1);
bands = zeros(N*N, 4); % Assuming there are 4 eigenvalues for each Hamiltonian

% Generate k-points within the Brillouin zone
count = 0;
for m1 = 1:N-1
    for m2 = 1:N-1
        kx = (m1/N) * G1(1) + (m2/N) * G2(1);
        ky = (m1/N) * G1(2) + (m2/N) * G2(2);

        % Corrected Brillouin zone restriction
        if norm([kx, ky]) <= norm(G1) && norm([kx, ky]) >= 0
            count = count + 1;
            kx_points(count) = kx;
            ky_points(count) = ky;

            fk = -t0 * (exp(-1i * kx * a) + 2 * exp(1i * kx * a / 2) * cos(sqrt(3) / 2 * ky * a));

            Hamiltonian = [0, fk, 0, 0;
                fk', 0, t1, 0;
                0, t1, 0, fk;
                0, 0, fk', 0];

            eigenvalues = sort(real(eig(Hamiltonian))); % Sort eigenvalues

            bands(count, :) = eigenvalues;
        end
    end
end

% Remove unused rows in the k_points array
kx_points = kx_points(1:count);
ky_points = ky_points(1:count);
bands = bands(1:count, :);

% % Sort k-points and bands by kx to create a smooth band structure plot
 [kx_points, sortedIndices] = sort(kx_points);
 bands = bands(sortedIndices, :);
%%
figure;
hold on;
for i = 1:size(bands, 2)
    plot(kx_points, bands(:, i));
end
xlabel('kx');
ylabel('Energy');
title('Band Structure of Bilayer Graphene');
legend('Band 1', 'Band 2', 'Band 3', 'Band 4'); % Adjust for the number of bands
hold off;
```

Comment: I think this is not really a programming issue and i guess you will find more luck in Physics Stuck Exchange (https://physics.stackexchange.com/)